# Possible off-by one error in a solution of a geometric distribution problem: $X\ge 5$ instead of $X\ge 6$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

### The Problem

The problem I am having trouble with is as follows:

> An urn contains five red balls, three white balls, six black balls, and six blue balls.
>   Assume that the sample is drawn successively and independently with replacement
>   from the urn.
>
> Find the probability that at least six draws are needed to observe the first red ball.

---

### My problem

In the problem I assumed that this was a geometric distrubtion $X$~geometric p=.25, and that $P\{X\geq 6\}=1-P\{X<6\}=1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{5}(.75)^{i-1}(.25)$ would be the probability associated with the answer. But looking at the actually solution to the problem shows that $P\{X\geq 5\}=1-P\{X<4\}=1-[1-(.75)^{5}]$ is the actually answer. My problem is why $P\{X\geq 5\}$ instead of $P\{X\geq 6\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers are correct. They look different because they use different conventions for the meaning of $X$ in [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution): the number of trials vs. the number of failures.

The condition "at least six draws are needed" means the same as "there are at least 5 failures". Hence, $X\ge 5$ where $X$ means the number of failures.

Focusing on the failures also leads to the simpler solution than yours: the probability that the first $5$ tries all fail is $0.75^5$, and that is the answer. (It is the same answer as yours.)